# SQL SELECT WHERE A THEN B

Tags: mysql, sql

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$search}%'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%{$search}%'
```

I want to get both 2 queries in one like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$search}%' then `tags` LIKE '%{$search}%'
```

I get priority of search result for games with Title = search word First,
then showing less-important results for tags = search word.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a `case` expression in the `ORDER BY` to return title matches first:

```
SELECT *
FROM `games`
WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `tags` LIKE '%{$search}%'
ORDER BY case when `title` LIKE '%{$search}%' then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: this is what im looking for. is this possible to work with A then B then C too?

Comment: I think if you choose this solution, that you can add other clause to the order (separated by a ',') : ```ORDER BY case when `title` LIKE '%{$search}%' then 0 else 1 end, case when `otherColumn` LIKE '%{$search}%' then 0 else 1 end```

Comment: thank you Omar, i've got it. ORDER BY 'case' is new for me.